# Create a dataframe from a list in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list `Path` from which I want to create a `dataframe` with the following characteristics: 2 columns, `number` and `uri` and as many rows as positions in my `Path` list.

```
> Path
[[1]]
[1] S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20190818T175529_20190818T175554_028627_033D25_22ED.SAFE

[[2]]
[1] S2A_MSIL1C_20190823T061631_N0208_R034_T42TXS_20190823T081730.SAFE
```

For this I am starting to use this code.

```
df <- data.frame(number = c(1:length(Path)),
                 uri = c(Path[[1]], Path[[2]]))
```

The `number` column is already linked to the dimension of the `Path` list using `1:length(Path)`, However, how can I populate the `uri` column accordingly. Meaning, the value of `Path[[1]]` should be in `row 1`, `column uri`, and so on in case `Path` has more values?

-- EDIT --

I would need to add a third column to the `dataframe` which content should depend on the value of `Path[[i]]`. The third column would be called `plugin` and

- if `Path` starts by `S1`, the value of `pluging` for that row should be `"class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn"`
- if `Path` starts by `S2`, the value of `pluging` for that row should be `"class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM42N_ReaderPlugIn"`

For this, I was thinking to use the `grepl('S2', Path)` code to check the condition but then I am not sure how to assign the appropriate value in the `dataframe`

Answer (score 3):

An option is `stack` from `base R` to create a two-column `data.frame` after naming the `list` of `vector`s with sequence

```
stack(setNames(Path, seq_along(Path)))[2:1]
```

---

Or another option is to `unlist` the `list` and create the `data.frame` (assume the `list` elements to be of `length` 1)

```
data.frame(number = seq_along(Path), url = unlist(Path))
```

If the elements of `list` have unequal `length`

```
data.frame(number = rep(seq_along(Path), lengths(Path)), url = unlist(Path))
```

---

Or we can use `enframe` from `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)   
library(dplyr) 
enframe(Path, name = "number", value = "url") %>%
      unnest %>%
      mutate(Plugin = case_when(substr(url, 1, 2) == "S1" ~ "class org.esa.s1tbx.io.sentinel1.Sentinel1ProductReaderPlugIn", TRUE ~ "class org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.s2.ortho.plugins.Sentinel2L1CProduct_Multi_UTM42N_ReaderPlugIn"))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to create a 3rd column using an if statment to choose the content? Something like `data.frame(......., plugin= if (grepl('S2', Path)) {...}` @akrun

Comment: @GCGM  Baesd on the example you provided, I am not sure what the content.  Is it a logical TRUE/FALSE column?

Comment: Won't `enframe` create that sequence of numbers if no other `name` argument is specified? Then you don't need the call to `set_names`

Comment: @akrun facing the following error: `Error in is_null(name) : object 'number' not found`

Comment: @akrun  facing now `could not find function "mutate"`. From which pck are you taking it? I may have a conflict

Comment: @GCGM  I usually write `library(tidyverse)` to take care off all the packages.  Here, it is `library(dplyr)` updated

Comment: @akrun that solved the issue. I am trying to follow your script, basically the `enframe` method does the same as `data.frame(number = seq_along(Path), url = unlist(Path))`. Then not sure how`unnest` and `mutate` are working. Of course I see the final result is good so I assume they do the right thing

Comment: @GCGM  By default, the `enframe` returns the `value' columns as a `list` and by `unnest`ing it unlist the `list` and expand the data.frame, then we use `mutate` on the full dataset to create a new column based on a condition i.e. we extract the prefix 'S2' with `substr` check whether it is equal to S1 or S2 and then change values

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility using `purrr`:

```r
map_df(Path, ~as.data.frame(.x), .id="id")
```

or in `base`:

```r
do.call(rbind, Map(f = expand.grid, l = Path, n = seq_along(Path), stringsAsFactors = F))
```